# Trying to apply multiple styles to a DataGridRow

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF application, i created DataGrid style in App.xaml to apply whole application.

App.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" x:Key="GridStyle1">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
    <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="RowStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then in window :

window1.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
</Style>
```

The problem that window style does not apply ( font style not italic )

Comment: If you are in fact applying `GridStyle1` to your `DataGrid`, then that style is setting the style for `DataGridRow` in that `DataGrid`, and the default style you created is of course being ignored. Are your `DataGridRow`s appearing with a Cyan background? Try adding the same `BasedOn` attribute to the style that sets the cyan background. That's probably the one actually being used. There may be other issues, but try that first.

Comment: I tried add same BaseOn attribute to Cyan background, but it is useless, the same result i get, ( Cyan background applied, but FontStyle not Italic ).

Comment: did you add the fontstyle to that one too?

Comment: i want apply Fontstyle from Window1 only not whole application, that is why i add it in Window1

Comment: I don't have all your code in front of me so I can't guess what you're trying to do. If you want a datagrid in Window1 to be italic, set a RowStyle that does that directly on that grid in Window1. You don't have to use the DataGrid style to do everything.

Comment: Thanks for interesting , my application has many windows, i create App style to apply to all windows when i set Style for DataGrid to GridStyle1, in Window1 I have three DataGrids i want apply default style (GridStyle1) for all of them in additional to FontStyle, if i add RowStyle to Window1 DataGrid it will apply successfully but default style will **not** apply, that is italic fontstyle but background is not Cyan :(

Comment: yes, you can only apply one style at a time in WPF. I'll be back in an hour -- there's a way around this

Comment: I want apply both of them, that why i add BaseOn attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to apply a global style to every `DataGridRow` in every `DataGrid` in multiple windows, and you also want to apply *additional* styling to `DataGridRow` in one or more `DataGrid`s in one particular window.

If you've learned CSS before, you may expect stylesheets to be cumulative: In CSS, if you apply `tr.style1` globally and `tr.style2` locally, you get both, with `tr.style2` winning the toss in any cases where they set the same attribute.

**That's not how styles work in XAML.** In XAML, an element may inherit styling from its parent, but it can have at most one `Style` of its own. Additionally, as you've found, `Style` has a `BasedOn` property. You can base one style on another, and get the cumulative effects of both.

Lastly, there are several ways to apply a style. You've found that you can apply them to every element of a given type in a given scope.

Unfortunately, because everything depends on context, the way XAML styles are applied can be very confusing at first (and at second, and sometimes third). Particularly when you are using one style (`GridStyle1`) to apply another style. It's not always obvious what overrides what.

It's best to keep things as simple as possible. We'll get rid of that `RowStyle` setter, because we don't need it. We'll just create a global `DataGridRow` `Style` that applies by default to every `DataGridRow` everywhere, and then we'll override that specifically in window1.xaml.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

**window1.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

That will apply to every `DataGridRow` in that window. The `BasedOn` attribute there will refer to whatever style has already been defined for `DataGridRow` in any containing context -- commonly, that means App.xaml, and if we don't add anything else, that'll be the case here.

The difference between this and what you had is that you were applying the Cyan `Background` style in a different way: The `DataGridRow` style you applied in App.xaml was applied via the `RowStyle` setter on your `DataGrid` style. That style was `BasedOn` WPF's pre-existing default `Style` for `DataGridRow`, and then it was forcibly applied to every `DataGridRow` in every `DataGrid` that used the `GridStyle1` style.

The `DataGridRow` style you defined in window1.xaml *would* have applied, if `DataGrid.RowStyle` hadn't already been set in `GridStyle1`.

But as we've seen, you don't need to use `RowStyle` to apply a style globally to every `DataGridRow`. You can do that with the default style for that type, as in my App.xaml fragment above. `DataGrid.RowStyle` is useful for *individually* overriding the global `DataGridRow` style on one particular `DataGrid`. But you don't want to do that globally! So your styles in App.xaml should look like this:

**App.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" x:Key="GridStyle1">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
    <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="30" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Cyan" />
</Style>
```

And again, here's the `Style` in **window1.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
</Style>
```

## Extra Credit

The styles above should solve your problem.

But there are other ways to approach this stuff. Unless you're very comfortable with what we did above, what follows may just add confusion, so if you start reading this and you find that the more you read, the less you understand -- then stop reading! It can wait!

You could also make all text in a `DataGrid` be italic, but that changes the headers too so I don't think it's what you want:

```
<DataGrid 
    FontStyle="Italic"
    />
```

If you want to apply that `Italic` style on just one grid in window1.xaml, here's how to do that. If we add an `x:Key` attribute to a `Style`, it won't be applied to every `DataGridRow` in scope. Instead, it's just sitting there, waiting to be used by name as a `StaticResource`.

**window1.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ItalicDataGridRowStyle" 
           TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<-- ... -->

<!-- One grid with italic rows -->
<DataGrid
    x:Name="dataGrid1"
    RowStyle="{StaticResource ItalicDataGridRowStyle}"
    />

<!-- And another grid with default rows -->
<DataGrid
    x:Name="dataGrid2"
    />
```

And here's another way to apply styling to the rows in just one grid in window1.xaml:

```
<!-- Yet another grid -->
<DataGrid
    x:Name="dataGrid3"
    >
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource ItalicDataGridRowStyle}">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Finally, you *could* have set `RowStyle` in `GridStyle1`, and then explicitly set `RowStyle` on specific grids in specific windows, as above. That would work. You could have also created a new `DataGrid` style in window1.xaml (based on `GridStyle1`) which set `RowStyle` to something else.